# Troubleshooting model binding problem in ASP.NET Core 3.1 API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to send an object via a `POST` request to my ASP.NET Core 3.1 API but I keep getting `Bad Request` error. As far as I can see, I do have a class that matches what I'm expecting **perfectly** but clearly it's not. How can I see exactly what the problem is?

The following fails:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] MyCustomObject input)
{
   // Do something here...
}
```

If I use a `dynamic`, it works fine. So the following code works fine:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] dynamic input)
{
   // Do something here...
}
```

As I said, I'm just getting a `400`, `Bad Request` error. I've been going over `MyCustomObject` again and again and it looks **identical** to the object that I'm sending.

Here's what my custom class looks like:

```
public class CreateContactVm
{
    [GuidEmptyNotAllowed]
    public Guid AccountId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string AccountName { get; set; }

    [GuidEmptyNotAllowed]
    public Guid ContactGroupId { get; set; }

    [IntZeroNotAllowed]
    public int ContactType { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string EntityName { get; set; }

    public List<AddEmailVm> Emails { get; set; } = new List<AddEmailVm>();

    public List<AddPhoneNumberVm> PhoneNumbers { get; set; } = new List<AddPhoneNumberVm>();

    public List<AddAddressVm> Locations { get; set; } = new List<AddAddressVm>();
}
```

Here, I use some custom validations such as `[GuidEmptyNotAllowed]` or `[IntZeroNotAllowed]`. I inspect the object I send via my `POST` call and it satisfies ALL of these requirements and yet it still fails.

How can I get more information about why my API method is throwing a `400` error?

UPDATE:

The following code allows me to convert what comes in as a `dynamic` to my `CreateContactVm` custom class but I really shouldn't have to do this at all:

```
CreateContactVm request = new CreateContactVm();

try
{
    var element = (JsonElement)input; // input is the dynamic received
    request = JsonUtils.Deserialize<CreateContactVm>(element.GetRawText());
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    var error = e.Message;
}
```

This also proves that the issue is with model binding. Something in my custom class is not liking the `JSON` object it receives.

Comment: What does your classes internals look like?

Comment: Did you post a from as JSON format? What's your `Content-type` header of your request? What's the content of the posted JSON? What's the `MyCUstomObject` like?

Comment: Not too complex but it's got quite a few properties, some of which are arrays. I also use validation to make sure I get data in some properties e.g. `[Required]` for `FirstName` property as well as some of my own custom validations. I was sure this was causing the issue so I disabled all validations.

Comment: I updated the original post with my custom class

Comment: @Anduin Yes, it's `JSON`. See the custom object in original post.

Comment: Assuming you are using VS, Is there any exception in your output window? What does the posted JSON look like?

Comment: @t.karalis Not getting any exceptions. I know my action method returns a `400` because I see it on the client side. Other than that, no errors. As I said, using a `dynamic` fixes the issue so it's definitely a model binding issue. I just need to figure out how I can get more info about model binding error.

Comment: @t.karalis As far as I can see, my `JSON` object that I send via `POST` is an EXACT match to my custom class. However, there must be something somewhere that is not matching perfectly. I've been inspecting both my `JSON` object and custom class for hours and I see nothing different between the two.

Comment: Gotya, model binding can be painful. One way would be to inspect the data going from client to server with a tool like fiddler, but sounds like its not the data thats the problem but the binder. I have tons of trouble in the past binding to collections within collections, do you have any further nested collections?

Comment: Could you try removing the list props and see if that works? Have you checked your ModelState to see if there is any errors coming through there?

Comment: How are you displaying the lists client side? With a for loop or a foreach. The model binder needs a for loop in order for it to bind.

Comment: @t.karalis See my update in original post. If I jump through hoops, I can convert what I receive into my custom class. Also, you were asking me about displaying lists. On the client side, I send arrays. My frontend is React so it's all JavaScript. I use this approach all the time and it works fine. Something in this particular class and its properties are causing the issue. Not sure what it is yet.

Comment: FIGURED IT OUT!!! It was two properties in my `AddAddressVm` class which is used in `Locations` property in my `CreateContactVm` custom object. I have two `string` properties in my `AddAddressVm` class i.e. Longitude and Latitude. On the frontend, I use a Google API to find a location which returns the longitude and latitude values as numeric values! That was the problem. My frontend was creating a `JSON` object with numeric values for these two properties but my backend was expecting `string` values. Insane!!!

Comment: So the final lesson here is that the `ModelBinder` is very very picky and if one will use these complex classes, it requires extreme precision. Otherwise, use some type of conversion approach to account for potential errors.